# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Signalr

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Signalr as a communication method in javascript based data driven applications written in asp .net MVC?

Thank you,

Comment: In what sense and compared to what?

Comment: question if perfectly fine for someone who is new to this, like me, only real developers who used this can tell something about it, using this means, they must have gone through everything else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, you shouldn't use SignalR unless you need what it offers, which is to say, a simple, duplex web service layer focusing on JavaScript clients. If you're brand-new to ASP.NET, that's probably not what you're going to need right away - you've got a lot of other stuff to learn before you can get around to writing complex, data-driven JavaScript applications. And if you're only going to be working with .NET clients, stick with WCF: it's more flexible and its static typing is a better fit with C# and VB.NET.

That said, when you *do* need a .NET-based web service backend for a JavaScript application, SignalR is a pretty good choice. It's certainly simpler to configure than Windows Communication Foundation, and for JavaScript apps, has a much better set of functionality. It seems to be sponsored by Microsoft (they're allowing it to sit in the Microsoft.AspNet namespace), and the folks responsible for it seem to be smart and very hard-working (if a tad acerbic at times). I once reported a bug at midnight, had a response within 15 minutes, and a fix by the time I got up in the morning. It's open-source, of course, and they're willing to consider pull requests, so if there's something you need fixed, you're going to have better luck than with Microsoft's previous closed-source model.

The only real downside to it is that it's pretty new - it recently reached 1.0 RC1 status - and is hence missing some features that would be nice to have, and still has some bugs (these will eventually get fixed, of course).

Here's an example of how it's still a bit new. One issue that you'll almost certainly run into if you're trying to serialize complex object graphs is that it uses Json.NET's proprietary format for object references, and so you end up with a lot of JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "$id": "57",
  "Name": "_default",
  "User": {
      "$id": "58",
      "UserTag": "ken",
      "Sessions": [{
          "$id": "59",
          "SessionId": "0ca7474e-273c-4eb2-a0c1-1eba2f1a711c",
          "User": {
              "$ref": "58"
          },
          "Room": {
              "$ref": "57"
          }
      }],
  },

  "Sessions": [{
      "$ref": "59"
  }]
}
```

It's not terribly helpful to read a `Session[]` array, and discover that the only object in it isn't a `Session` at all, but an arbitrary object with a single `$ref` property. To get around this, you'll need to wrap all your SignalR calls with something like [JsonNetDecycle](https://bitbucket.org/smithkl42/jsonnetdecycle). Not difficult, but something that would be nice to have handled in SignalR itself. (And of course, if I were a better person, I'd code it up myself and submit it as a pull request - just haven't gotten around to it yet.)